# How to calculate F-statistic from glmnet

Tags: goodness-of-fit, glmnet, f-statistic

I understand how to obtain coefficients and MSE from `glmnet`. Now my question is: How can I calculate the goodness of fit of the model in terms of standard measures, i.e. F-statistics AIC or alike?

Comment: To give a bit of context: I want to use a LASSO regression as a first stage in a instrumental variable (IV) regression and in economics, it is standard to report the F-stat of the first stage